# Cannot mount partitions from LSI Software MegaRAID

Tags: raid, software-raid, lsi, megaraid

I have a ThinkServer RD440 running RHEL 7.2 with a **LSI MegaRAID** which is configured as a RAID 10 over 4 disks. It is configured on a partition level, not the raw disks. The root partition is not part of the RAID. For various reasons the original maintainer is no longer available and I don't have the root password. But I need to backup the data because we need the server.

I tried to create a USB drive with Ubuntu 15.10 and boot from it. This works as intended but I cannot mount the partitions that are part of the RAID because mount says it cannot find the superblocks. The disks are 1 TB each and this is what fdisk reports:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xe79b4f2
Device    Boot     Start        End    Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1           2048  209717247  209715200 100G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb2      209717248 3902341119 3692623872 1.7T 83 Linux

Disk /dev/sdc: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xe79b4f2
Device    Boot     Start        End    Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1           2048  209717247  209715200 100G 83 Linux
/dev/sdc2      209717248 3902341119 3692623872 1.7T 83 Linux

Disk /dev/sdd: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/sde: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

The **LSI Software RAID Configuration Utility**, that can be accessed at boot time, says that the disks are healthy and are part of the RAID. RHEL also boots without any problem.

Does anybody know how I can get the partitions mounted? Am I missing a driver that RHEL has but Ubuntu doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, sometimes one is pretty dumb. I generated a new root password with the following command and restarted the server:

```
openssl passwd -1 newpassword
```